# Cloud Run GCP Spring Boot cant read input file pdf

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I try to load a PDF file on Goolgle Cloud Platform Cloud Run Spring Boot but it can't read the file to send it to Firebase storage. Is there any reason why I can't load the file? It works locally on my computer but when deployed get 500 internal server error "cant read input file Order 123456789.pdf.

Cloud Run isn't writing my files to disk. It works locally on my machine. Is there any reason why Cloud Run won't write a file to disk?

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake. As part of my PDF generation I was trying to access an image file on my local filesystem which was not in the project folder. Removed it from pdf generation now it works. Thanks guys.